# Connect wireless Epson Printer

Tags: wireless, printing, epson

Is it possible to use the Epson xp-235a with Kubuntu, complete as a wireless printer? If so, where can I find the required drivers and set up procedure?
Thanks in advance,
Rene.

Answer (score 8):

For Epson XP 231, XP 240, ET2851 & WF-M5690 for Ubuntu 16.04 / 23.04, I did the following steps:

Windows

- I configured with a Windows 10 the printer (to enter my wifi and upgrade firmware).

On Ubuntu

- I installed driver package with:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr
```

- I entered "System Settings -> Printers -> Add"
- In Network Printer it appeared, I selected it and selected the recommended driver

P.S: I tried to install the drivers mentioned from Epson, but only a scanner driver appeared on the official page (and it didn't work).

P.S.2: thanks everyone on your comments on expanding my solution to other printers! Still using my XP 231 after so many years, very happy from it.

Comment: Also works for XP430, though the recommended driver is EPSON X-432 435 Series. Tested in Linux Mint 18

Comment: the lsb package is needed at least for later ubuntu versions ("sudo apt-get install lsb" )

Comment: The printer-driver-escpr solution works also for the Epson ET2851 printer model.

Comment: This is the solution that actually worked for my WF-M5690 on Ubuntu 22.04, as opposed to tutorials with Epson's own drivers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this printer with Ubuntu.

Epson drivers for Linux are [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

Most of Epson drivers are installed automatically form the Ubuntu Partner repository when you install a printer in System Settings.